# Extending View with extra function without using AnyView

Tags: swift, view, swiftui

I am doing this:

```
extension View {
    func isHidden(_ hidden: Bool) -> AnyView {
        AnyView(hidden ? self.hidden() : self)
    }
}
```

I would prefer something like this:

```
extension View {
    func isHidden(_ hidden: Bool) -> some View {
        return hidden ? self.hidden() : self
    }
}
```

Is this possible and/or am I worrying needlessly? thx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. Here it is

```
extension View {
    func isHidden(_ hidden: Bool) -> some View {
        Group {
            if hidden {
                self.hidden()
            }
            else {
                self
            }
        }
    }
}
```